# Handling mouse event on React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events, onmousemove

I am trying to use JavaScript mouse event like onMousemove to create DOM element on React component, but I am facing a glitch.

I have a working vanilla JavaScript version which works correctly.

Here is my broken code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vmvvr25147

Here is a working vanilla javascript version: http://jsfiddle.net/d9BPz/546/

Here is my main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Popup, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './ManageRectangleHotSpots.css';

class ManageRectangleHotSpots extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dimensions: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
      },
      mouse: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
      }
    }
  }

  canvas = null;
  element = null;

  setMousePosition = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      mouse: {
        ...this.state.mouse,
        x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
        y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY
      }
    });
  }

  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    this.setMousePosition(e);
    if (this.element !== null) {

      console.log(e.nativeEvent.offsetX, e.nativeEvent.offsetY);
      this.element.style.width = Math.abs(this.state.mouse.x - this.state.mouse.startX) + 'px';
      this.element.style.height = Math.abs(this.state.mouse.y - this.state.mouse.startY) + 'px';
      this.element.style.left = (this.state.mouse.x - this.state.mouse.startX < 0) ? this.state.mouse.x + 'px' : this.state.mouse.startX + 'px';
      this.element.style.top = (this.state.mouse.y - this.state.mouse.startY < 0) ? this.state.mouse.y + 'px' : this.state.mouse.startY + 'px';
    }
  }

  onMouseDown = (e) => {
    console.log("begun.");
    this.setState({
      mouse: {
        ...this.state.mouse,
        startX: this.state.mouse.x,
        startY: this.state.mouse.y
      }
    });

    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.className = 'rectangle'
    this.element.style.left = this.state.mouse.x + 'px';
    this.element.style.top = this.state.mouse.y + 'px';

    this.canvas.appendChild(this.element)
    this.canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

  }

  onMouseUp = (e) => {

    this.element = null;
    this.canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    this.setState({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      startX: 0,
      startY: 0
    });

    console.log("finsihed.");
  }

  setCanvas = (c) => {
    this.canvas = c;
  }

  onLoadImg = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      dimensions: {
        width: e.target.width,
        height: e.target.height
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="wrapper">     
        <Image src={this.props.imagePath} onLoad={ this.onLoadImg } />    
        <div className="canvasWrapper" >
          <div 
            className="canvas" 
            style={{ width: this.state.dimensions.width, height: this.state.dimensions.height }} 
            ref={ this.setCanvas } 
            onMouseDown={ this.onMouseDown }
            onMouseUp={ this.onMouseUp }
            onMouseMove={ this.onMouseMove }
            >
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ManageRectangleHotSpots;
```

Comment: I can see two issues. `onMouseDown` does not use clicked x,y position and you are working with synthetic events https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html.   Either use `event.persist()` or better temporarily save the `e.nativeEvent` to a variable because `setState` is executed async and e.nativeEvent values might be missing at that time.

Comment: `onMouseDown` uses clicked x,y position from component state which is updated constantly using `onMouseMove`

Comment: So you suggest that I extract `e.nativeEvent` from every call to `setState` by saving it a variable. right ?

Comment: I have tried using `event.persist()`, caching `e.nativeEvent` to a variable and event get rid of component `state` and use only local variables. but the gotcha remains.

Comment: It looks like that `event` properties get updated with existing rectangles or currently being drawn one. is there a way that we always work with canvas properties ?

Comment: I re-examined the problem. If you want it to behave exactly like the vanilla version, then you should use `onClick` event and skip onMouseDown and onMouseUp, they are for holding down the mouse-button. I have created rough example this forked from your example, could be cleaned up, but you get the idea - https://codesandbox.io/s/l5vk9vo15q

Comment: I have narrow down my issue and I have found that it's on `getMousePosition` methode.

When I use `e.nativeEvent.offsetX` I got the glitch mentioned in my issue.
And when I use `e.pageX` I don't get the first glitch but I get an offset equivalent to parent offset.

So finding the offset of the parent element in react will fix my issue.

Comment: get rid of browser compatibility and use this function to find the patch solution. https://imgur.com/a/Fm6hL

Comment: Take a look at the glitch after trying to sub-struct parent offset, I have modified getMousePosition of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/qknxnk3v9q